# Android ListViews and Dynamic Section Headers

Tags: android, listview, header

I have an Array that I pass to a CustomAdapter for a ListView. The array has items that are already sorted. Something like:

```
[{"stuff":[{"stuff_id": "1", "value":"test123"},
 {"stuff_id": "1", "value":"test123"},
 {"stuff_id": "2", "value":"test123"}]}]
```

The Array changes allot so I do not know haw many sections I will have. So far I am finding weird results when using a device versus using the emulator. For instance, I Logcat the position in the getView() method every time its called and with the emulator, I only get 0 once. With a device (Motorola Droid - 2.1), every forth row or so is position 0. I figure it has something to do with the screen size and reuse but i am not sure.

I tried to use login like, if(position == 0) draw section header and then if(stuff_id != previous_stuff_id) draw section header. But since the position goes back to zero, I get header rows where I should not.

Anyone seen these types of results and know how to fix them?

Comment: Can you explain how it actually should like if it's done correct? I can't really imagine.

Comment: The first two rows would have a section header of "1" (lame but follows my example). The third row would have "2" for a section header.

Comment: I don't know if it is the best solution but I would try to split the array before drawing the view. So i would define a List for every stuff_id and then for every List i would define a separate Listview. Then you can use the following layout: section_header_of_1 / list_view_of_1 / section_header_of_2 / list_view_of_2 etc